# ENOENT error while deploying Cloud Functions to Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-cli

I am using Cloud Functions to send a user a notification when the Realtime Database is updated.

I selected "javascript" when I created the project using `firebase init functions` and am running Windows 10.

Whenever I use `firebase deploy` it shows me this error:

```
Error: spawn npm --prefix "I:\Indian Meme Templates\functions" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase- 
     tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
{
    code: 'ENOENT',
    errno: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "I:\\Indian Meme Templates\\functions" run lint',
    path: 'npm --prefix "I:\\Indian Meme Templates\\functions" run lint',
    spawnargs: []
}
```

This is my `Index.js` file:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.sendAdminNotification = functions.database.red('\Data/{pushId}').onWrite(evet =>){

    const data = event.data.val();
    if(data.priority==1){
        const payload = { notification: 
            {title: 'New Data',
             body: '${data.title}'
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("News",payload).then(function(response))
        {
            console.log('Notification sent successfully: ',response);
        }).catch(function(error)){
            console.log('Notification sent failed: ',error);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The cause of this error is that during deployment, the `firebase deploy` operation is attempting to lint (proof-read) your code but it cannot find the tool and/or file used to lint your code.

The first step to try and solve this is to make sure that you have installed all dependencies in your `functions` folder using `npm run install`. This will make sure that the `eslint` tool is installed.

Next, because the `npm run lint` command is setup to call `eslint .` by default, your `Index.js` file should be renamed to `index.js`. This is because `index.js` has special meaning in Javascript/Typescript projects as the default entry point of a folder. Most tools will expect that naming conventions are followed and that it is in lowercase.

Next, the `index.js` file you provided has a number of typos (that should be highlighted when the lint tool does it's job).

Here is the same code, rewritten without those typos:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendAdminNotification = functions.database.ref('/Data/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
    const data = event.data.val();
    if (data.priority == 1) {
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'New Data',
                body: '${data.title}'
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("News", payload)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log('Notification sent successfully: ', response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Notification sent failed: ', error);
            });
    }
});
```

I recommend working in an IDE such as [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) or [Atom](https://atom.io) if you are just starting out with using Firebase as it will help you with code hinting, live linting and syntax highlighting.